# awk - AWK variable in if condition

Tags: awk

How can a variable in an `awk` command be used to read a column of a file in an `if` condition?

e.g. Say to read column 2 of a below sample file, in which `fcolumn1` holds value as `2`, `startdate` as `2014-09-22 00:00:00`, and `enddate` as `2014-09-23 00:00:00`.

```
abcd,2016-04-23 02:35:34,sdfsdfsd
sdsd,2016-04-22 02:35:34,sdfsdfsd
```

Below command works:

```
awk -v startdate="$startdate" -v enddate="$enddate" -F"," '
{ 
    if ($2>=startdate && $2<enddate)
    { 
        print $2
    }   

}'
```

Expectation is to make `$2` as dynamic as below:

```
awk -v startdate="$startdate" -v enddate="$enddate" -v "fcolumn1=${fcolumn1}" -F"," '
{ 
    if (fcolumn1 != "")
    {

        if (**$fcolumn1**>=startdate && **$fcloumn1**<enddate)
        { 
            print "$fcolum1"
        }   
    }
}'
```

Answer (score 1):

First, the `if` block is superfluous since `awk` programs follow the following (simplified) structure:

```
 CONDITION { ACTIONS } CONDITION {ACTIONS} ...
```

You can write the condition without the `if` statement:

```
awk '$2>=startdate && $2<enddate { print $2 }' file
```

---

If you want to make the actual column number configurable via a variable, note that you can address a column using a variable in `awk`, like this:

```
awk -v col=2 '{print $col}'
```

Comment: I want to make $2 dynamic from variable.

Comment: If you want to make  the column number a variable, you can use : `awk -v col=2 '$col <= startdate { ... }'`